# Setting Apache CXF bus properties for malicious xml

Tags: java, spring, web-services, cxf

I am trying to set CXF bus properties for malicious xml as below

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:sec="http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security"
    xmlns:http="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"
    xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd
      http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/security.xsd
      http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

    <cxf:bus>
        <cxf:properties>
            <entry key="org.apache.cxf.stax.maxAttributeSize" value="1"/>
            <entry key="org.apache.cxf.stax.maxChildElements" value="1"/>
            <entry key="org.apache.cxf.stax.maxElementDepth" value="1"/>
            <entry key="org.apache.cxf.stax.maxAttributeCount" value="1"/> 
            <entry key="org.apache.cxf.stax.maxTextLength" value="1"/>
            <entry key="org.apache.cxf.stax.maxElementCount" value="1"/>
      </cxf:properties>
    </cxf:bus>
</beans>
```

It seems like these properties are not picked up by CXF. Above code is in spring context xml file. Whenever I do a post request which has more than one elements and child elements, CXF does not throw any error. I am using CXF version 3.1.1

Comment: It may be trivial, but you're using a version> CXF 2.7.4

Comment: I am using version 3.1.1

Comment: Make sure `woodstock` is in the classpath and being used. `org.apache.cxf.stax.allowInsecureParser` must be `false` (it is the default value)

Comment: I added woodstock to my pom file and I can see it in my classpath. How can I set property "org.apache.cxf.stax.allowInsecureParser". I don't see any documentation on cxf site? Thanks

Comment: It is an environment variable. Do not worry about it if you had no setted before, because default value is false. Check also deployment options for your server to ensure woodstock is loaded. http://cxf.apache.org/docs/application-server-specific-configuration-guide.html. CXF documentation says that this library will be used to perform the validations

Comment: Woodstock is now in classpath but no luck. I put a breakpoint on CXFBusImpl just to figure out if bus is getting accessed, but it seems like its not. I think I am missing something in CXF configuration. How can I make sure CXF bus is working?

Comment: Use the logging interceptor for inbound and outbound connections defined here http://cxf.apache.org/docs/configuration.html. to see if bus is acting. The cxf:bus is the default for endpoint, but if it does not works, define your own and reference it in jaxws server using bus="#yourbus". See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078685/where-to-add-cxfbus-inside-the-apache-cxf-endpoints-xml-file

Comment: Do I need to set any property for Woodstock or just adding its jar to classpath would work?

Comment: Just adding. I have tested the properties without problems. I have put the details in answer so you can compare

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tested the Bus properties with CXF 2.7.13 and 3.1.6 in a Tomcat server with java 1.6 and java 1.8, and in both cases the XML request was blocked as the documentation says.

Make sure woodstook and stax libraries are in classpath. CXF delegates XML check to those libraries. If the server has it owns XML parser. They have to be before the XML parser server (if available). Check [server configuration guide](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/application-server-specific-configuration-guide.html)

I am going to detail the configuration so you can check yours.

**CXF Dependencies (Ivy  format)**

```
 <dependency org="org.apache.cxf" name="cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs" rev="3.1.6" conf="default"/>
 <dependency org="org.apache.cxf" name="cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws" rev="3.1.6" conf="default"/>
 <dependency org="org.apache.cxf" name="cxf-rt-ws-security" rev="3.1.6" conf="default"/>
 <dependency org="org.apache.cxf" name="cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers" rev="3.1.6" conf="default"/>
```

**spring CXF config**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xmlns:http-conf="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd 
        http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd"
    default-lazy-init="false">

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />

    <!-- JAX-WS server-->
    <bean id="sampleEndPointImpl" class="com.SampleEndPointImpl" />
    <jaxws:endpoint id="sampleServiceSOAP" 
        address="/sampleEndPoint"
        endpointName = "SampleEndPoint"
        implementor="#sampleEndPointImpl" >
    </jaxws:endpoint>

    <!-- JAX-RS server-->
    <bean id="bookService" class="com.BookService" />
    <jaxrs:server id="bookservice" address="/">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="bookService" />
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    </jaxrs:server>

    <cxf:bus>
        <cxf:properties>
            <entry key="org.apache.cxf.stax.maxAttributeSize" value="1"/>
            <entry key="org.apache.cxf.stax.maxChildElements" value="1"/>
            <entry key="org.apache.cxf.stax.maxElementDepth" value="1"/>
            <entry key="org.apache.cxf.stax.maxAttributeCount" value="1"/> 
            <entry key="org.apache.cxf.stax.maxTextLength" value="1"/>
            <entry key="org.apache.cxf.stax.maxElementCount" value="1"/>
      </cxf:properties>

    </cxf:bus>


</beans>
```

**Sample REST server**

BookService.java

```
 @POST
 @Path("/test")
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
 public Response test(Book book) {
    return Response.ok(book.getName() + "123").build();
 }
```

Book.java

```
 @XmlRootElement(name = "Book")
 public class Book {
     private String name;

     public String getName() {return name;}
     public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}
 }
```

Request tested

```
 POST /test
 Content-Type:application/xml
 <Book><name>aaaa</name></Book>
```

**The error received**

```
 JAXBException occurred : Maximum Element Depth limit (1) Exceeded. Maximum Element Depth limit (1) Exceeded.
```

If you delete the `<cxf:bus>` section, CXF [default values](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/security.html#Security-ControllingLargeRequestPayloads) will be applied, and the XML example  will be processed

```
 aaaa123
```

Comment: Thanks for this :). After some debugging I see properties are getting set on bus but I think I am missing endpoints (The one listed in <jaxws:endpoints....>). I think pattern will be the same for REST?

Comment: I have doubts but with a jax-rs server also runs the XML filter. I have added the example

Comment: If you remove <cxf:bus> tag then who are you setting cxf properties for these limits?

Comment: Then the default values will be used http://cxf.apache.org/docs/security.html#Security-ControllingLargeRequestPayloads. If you want to apply different limits to each server, configure a `bus` and reference it from server using  `bus="#yourbus"`

Comment: No, I mean the REST example you gave and int that you said you were getting error "Maximum Element Depth limit (1)" by removing <cxf:bus> tag. How have you achieved this without setting properties.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could write the configuration for REST example too. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, It is misspelled! The configuration for REST is the same, the example has a jax-rs and a jax-ws server. Simply remove the jaxws section. I've left something?

Comment: Could you tell me what version of woodstox-core-asl and stax2-api library you are using

Comment: Check my test project https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwhbCLpp5gB7UmJUYl9jZU9oNUk/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Configuring on bus-level didn't work for me in any way with cxf 3.2.4.
After configuring on endpoint-level, everything works like a charm:

```
            <jaxws:endpoint address="/myEndpoint" id="myEndpoinId" implementor="#myEndpoint">
            <jaxws:properties>
                    <entry key="org.apache.cxf.stax.maxTextLength" value="536870912"/>
            </jaxws:properties> (...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Leaving another solution here if somebody seeks a fix an exception while using CXF 4.0.2 JAXWS standalone client:
`javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Maximum Element Depth limit (100) Exceeded`.

```java
System.setProperty(StaxUtils.MAX_ELEMENT_DEPTH, "1000");
JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
```

Unfortunately setting that property via `factory` doesn't fix the issue. So I would be more than happy to edit this answer if there is another way than global scoped one.